# WebApi Controller IQueryable contains few return. How to solve "not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here is webapi controller of IQuerybale that must return different queries result, but debugger said that "not all code paths return a value".

```
public IQueryable<xTourist> GetxTouristByCategory(string category)
        {
            var now = System.DateTime.MinValue;
            switch (category)
            {
                case "arrival":
                    now = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
                    return db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room == null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= now).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival);
                case "inhouse":
                    now = System.DateTime.Today;
                    return db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room != null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= now).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would your function return if `category` is not `arrival` nor `inhouse` ?

That's the reason why your compiler complains `not all code paths return a value`.

As an additional tip, you can re-factor your code to something like this:

```
    enum ECategory { Arrival, Inhouse };

    public IQueryable<xTourist> GetxTouristByCategory(ECategory category)
            {

                return (category = ECategory.Arrival) ?
                       db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room == null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival)
                     : db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room != null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= System.DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can put default case 

default: Return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess default is missing in switch statement, that's why it shows all code paths should return a value.

Add a default case in switch statement and use a return statement in it like this if there are only 2 cases.

```
public IQueryable<xTourist> GetxTouristByCategory(string category)
        {
            var now = System.DateTime.MinValue;
            switch (category)
            {
                case "arrival":
                    now = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
                    return db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room == null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= now).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival);

                default:
                    now = System.DateTime.Today;
                    return db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Room != null).Where(p => p.Arrival >= now).OrderByDescending(p => p.Arrival);


            }
        }
```

Note: If there are more than 2 cases (arrival and inhouse) you should modify this code for all cases and add a default case at the end.